# Dart: how to run static function/code "automatically"?

Tags: dart

In Dart (Flutter) I would like to have some static code run without being explicitly invoked.

I tried this:

```
// File 1
class MyClass {
    static int member = 42;
}

int dummy = 42;
```

and file 2:

```
// File 2
void main() {
    int tmp = MyClass.member;
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the `dummy = 2;` line but it seemed to never be invoked.

I also tried:

```
// File 1
class MyClass {
    static int member1 = 42;
    static int member2 = SomeOtherClass.someFunc();
}
```

and file 2:

```
// File 2
void main() {
    int tmp1 = MyClass.member1;
    int tmp2 = MyClass.member2;
}
```

With this, `SomeOtherClass.someFunc()` was invoked when the `int tmp2 = ...` line was invoked.

I would like `SomeOtherClass.someFunc()` to be invoked without explicitly accessing `MyClass.member2`. I would like it invoked on any of the following triggers:

1. When the program starts (before `main()` is called).
2. OR, when code in a file in which `MyClass` is imported is invoked for the first time.

Is either of these possible in Dart?

Comment: Static and global variables are initialized lazily when they're first accessed.  Consequently, you can't invoke Dart code before `main()`.  You also can't force code to be implicitly invoked as a result of `import`ing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is intentional and cannot be changed. As jamesdlin also explain, all static variables (class and global) in Dart are lazy evaluated and will first get a value with first attempt to access the value.

This is design is described in the Dart specification followed up with a reason for that design choice:

> Static variable declarations with an initializing expression are initializedlazily.
>
> *The lazy semantics are given because we do not want a language where one tends to define expensive initialization computations, causing long application startup times. This is especially crucial for Dart, which must support the coding of client applications.*

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

Comment: Thanks. This is disappointing... they cripple the language for everybody because someone somewhere might use a feature incorrectly...

Comment: @obe Not really sure that is the case really. I have used Dart for years and have not seen this restriction as a problem. It is actually rather great that you know that just importing something into your project does not results in random stuff to happen. Also, other languages are also kinda lazy when it comes to stuff like this (e.g. Java) so it is not really something unique. Since this is normal behavior in Dart, just document your API with a "please run `MyClass.initialize()` before using my package" if you need to run something in the start.

Comment: This is useful when writing frameworks or framework-level code. E.g. to register services in some repository for DI purposes without having to reference each one explicitly. I suppose it might be achievable with annotations instead (though the lack of reflection in runtime and the need to do stuff with code generation and extra build steps makes it harder).